# Issues with SWI-Prolog editor

Tags: editor, swi-prolog

Some time ago I was fiddling with SWI-Prolog editor, trying to get something to work, and I change some configuration settings. It didn't work so I changed it back. Now SWI-Prolog editor is not working correctly. I will load files but when I click 'consult' it will just throw this error:

> consult('C:/Users/Cubearth/Documents/Prolog/'filename.pl').

and I am not able to perform queries, on the knowledge base... it just does nothing. I know that it **should** return:

```
% library(win_menu) compiled into win_menu 0.00 sec, 20,952 bytes
% library(swi_hooks) compiled into pce_swi_hooks ......... (etc, etc)

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).
```

but I am not even getting that. I tried uninstalling both prolog and the editor, but still no luck.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

In order to help, I have included the configuration dump of prolog:

Installation

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\SWIPrologEditor\SWIMachine.ini
  C:\Users\Cubearth\AppData\Roaming\SWIPrologEditor\SWIUser.ini
  C:\Users\Cubearth\AppData\Roaming\SWIPrologEditor\SWIColor.ini

[SWI]
PortableApplication=0 
Verzeichnis=C:\Program Files\pl
Manual=C:\Program Files\pl\bin\doc\Manual\Contents.html
XPCE=C:\Program Files\pl\bin\doc\UserGuide\Contents.html 

[Program] 
InterpreterParameter=-L32M 
FileExtension=.pl 

[Editor] 
TabWidth=2 
Indent=2 
Indenthelp=1 
AutomaticIndent=1 
FileTab=1 
Linenumbering=1 
BracketPair=0 
CursorBehindLine=1 
Author= 
Encoding=0 
Structure=0 

[Code] 
Code-Completion=1 
Parameter-Hints=1 
Delay=100 

[Options] 
ColoredConsole=1 
IntegratedWindow=1 
ReturnToContinue=1 
TraceStopsDebugToo=1 
BAKFiles=1 
RemoveWriteProtection=1 
FileTabsMultiline=1 
Language=C:\Program Files (x86)\SWIPrologEditor\english.ini 

[Browser]
UseIEinternForDocuments=1 
OnlyOneBrowserWindow=0 
Browser=C:\Users\Cubearth\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe 
Title=unknown 
AltKeysBrowser= 
ProxyEnabled=0 
ProxyIP= 
ProxyPort=0

[Printer] 
Left=20 
Top=20
Right=20 
Bottom=20 
Header=#%PATH%#
Footer=##- %PAGENUM% -
Linenumbers=0 
LinenumbersInMargin=1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me enlighten the poor lost soul that is cubearth. You should double check to see which version of swi-prolog you installed (32-bit or 64-bit), because swi-prolog editor only works with the 32-bit version. If you tried using the editor with the 64-bit version, you'll get the error described above. ^^ .

p.s. You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Enable trace, run cmd --

```
?- trace. consult('C:/Users/Cubearth/Documents/Prolog/'filename.pl').
```